# Good book for logic self-study with answers to exercises

Tags: logic, soft-question, self-learning, big-list

I know a similar question has already been asked, but can anyone suggest a good book on mathematical logic that includes answers to exercises? I am looking for something that is conducive to self-study and knowing if I'm right or wrong with the exercises is very important to me. Thanks for any input.

Comment: See [this](http://www.logicmatters.net/resources/pdfs/TeachYourselfLogic9-3.pdf) self study guide created by MSE's user [Peter Smith](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/35151/peter-smith).

Comment: Maybe Smullyan's "First Order Logic". Exercises do not have answers, but the book is still valuable.

Comment: http://www.math.ucla.edu/~ynm/lectures/lnl.pdf

Comment: While it is designed for students making the transition to proof-based mathematics, you may find my tutorial useful, at least initially. It has 13 worked examples. At the end of each example, there are  exercises, each with hints and full solutions. The tutorial comes with my free proof-checking software downloadable at my website http://www.dcproof.com

Answer (score 5):

I picked Chiswell and Hodges "Introduction to Mathematical Logic" which I found in Peter Smith's guide and I personally regard it as one of the best mathematical book I have ever read. It has a lot of exercises many of them have full solutions. I am also self learner and I know how important are exercises with at least answers if not full solutions.

Answer (score 5):

A Friendly Introduction to Mathematical Logic 2nd Edition by Christopher C. Leary and Lars Kristiansen meets all your criteria.

The authors have made it freely available here: https://minerva.geneseo.edu/a-friendly-introduction-to-mathematical-logic/.

Comment: I strongly recommend **against** this book, because it has some fundamental conceptual flaws, such as [I mentioned in chat to someone who was confused by it](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/77161?m=57912124#57912124).